# problems with today extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, today-extension

I have a today extension that has a background download task and progress view that shows the download's progress.both working but there are 2 problems:

1. Although the download task is set to background as soon as I close
   the notification center download stops (I think this happens because the extension doesn't go background state like containing app does when you press the home button, instead, the extension is being terminated by the host app. So what's the solution?)
2. If you open the extension
   for the first time, progressView shows the progress but next time
   download task is being performed but nothing is shown in the
   progress.